# Are special conformal transformations continuous?

Tags: mathematical-physics, symmetry, conformal-field-theory, geometry

My understanding of special conformal transformations (SCTs) is fairly limited, but I believe that they are composed of an inversion, a translation and another inversion. Since inversions are discrete symmetries, I would assume that an SCT is also discrete. However, one can write a generator for them, which I thought could only be done for continuous symmetries.

Therefore, are SCTs continuous or discrete symmetries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [special conformal transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_conformal_transformation) (SCT) are continuous. One proof comes from the fact that SCTs are of the form $I\circ T\circ I$, where translations $T$ are continuous.

Moreover, SCF are connected to the identity, since translations $T$ are connected to the identity (and conformal inversion $I$ is [involutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))). And indeed there are generators $K_{\mu}$ for SCTs, as OP mentions.